# Swift 3.0 localization Bundle for enum

Tags: swift3

Using swift 3.0, I am trying to create enum where different values and their description will get as per enum type, depends on localization language. But below code is not compile due to Bundle parameters are not valid as here self is not valid class in enum. Any suggestion about how can we resolve this issue for localization?

```
public enum TempEnumValues : Int
{
    case first    
    case second
    case third    

    var values: Int
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .first:
            return 1

        case .second:
            return 2

        case .third:
            return 3
        }
    }

    var description: String
    {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: CLASS_NAME.self))

        switch self
        {
        case .first:
            return NSLocalizedString("First Value", bundle: bundle, comment: "")

        case .second:
            return NSLocalizedString("Second Value", bundle: bundle, comment: "")

        case .third:
            return NSLocalizedString("Third Value", bundle: bundle, comment: "")

        }
    }
}
```

I found the answer & updated code